# How to keep sync my Listview items with Sqlite Database and Files stored on SD Card?

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-file

I am working on a call recorder app which
1- Records every incoming outgoing calls through a service and service save every file on a folder "My Call Recorder" in sd card and also store call information to sqlite database like filepath, caller number, call duration, date and time of the call, call type(incoming or outgoing).
2. App's MainActivity contains a custom listview which populated from that sqlite database using Simple Cursor Adapter. After click on an item, i get cursor object from adapter then get file path from it and open another activity then play that media file using that file path. Here user can delete, move aur copy that media file. I can update sqlite database entries when file being deleted or moved.

**Problem**
Suppose user have 10 calls recorded and stored at sd card folder and somehow user deletes a file using a third party file manager app from that "My Call Recorder" folder but my app doesn't know about it and when user open my app, it still shows 10 list items because sqlite database is still has 10 entries. How can i keep my sqlite updated with files stored on sd card?

**Edit**
This is method which populates listview. Please suggest where to implement that file.exists method to check every file?

```
 public void populateListview() {
    db = new DBSQL(MainActivity.this);
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    String[] from = new String[]{"displayname", "fileduration", "filedatetime", "calltype"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvNumber, R.id.tvDuration, R.id.tvDateTime, R.id.img2};
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to);
        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int i) {
                if (i == (cursor.getColumnIndex("displayname"))) {
                    String displayName = cursor.getString(i);
                    String contactName = getContactName(displayName, MainActivity.this);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    if (contactName.isEmpty()) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        tv.setText(contactName);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {
        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if File exists when displaying the list

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists())
{ 
 //do nothing
}
else
{
 //remove entry from SqLite Table
}
```

Edit populateListview() like this

```
public void populateListview() {
db = new DBSQL(MainActivity.this);
cursor = db.getAllData();
String[] from = new String[]{"displayname", "fileduration", "filedatetime", "calltype"};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvNumber, R.id.tvDuration, R.id.tvDateTime, R.id.img2};
if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to);
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int i) {

            if (i == (cursor.getColumnIndex("displayname"))) {
                File f = new File(filePathString);
                if(!(f.exists()))
                { 
                  deleteRecordWithId(itemId);
                  cursor.requery();
                  notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                String displayName = cursor.getString(i);
                String contactName = getContactName(displayName, MainActivity.this);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                if (contactName.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    tv.setText(contactName);
                    return true;
                }


            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

} else {
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

Comment: Aravindraj, can you please suggest where to implement this file.exists method in my code? I have added my listview populate method in my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer .Please check whether you could fix the issue

Comment: Aravindraj, it says "Unreachable Statement" when inserted your code in my populatelistview method. Watch screenshot https://scontent.fisb3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/21687571_10155655943453396_5171839669156139219_n.jpg?_nc_eui2=v1%3AAeFqpAWjPb5ldJm2qG3hu1wSXtgA-7oucHT2AoERstCC65UL8xWAnSa4krtkJxVf7mHp3NAzOIqgEmDIT8jPH4ZLrw-8mYroaGSoOsxHOuEozSRnCAEdTxLzKhrVUl7k6fY&oh=ea8af863321f68e8785c8031b3aabed8&oe=5A49864A

Comment: Aravindraj, please review my above post.

Comment: Aravindraj, Implemented your edited code, just changed notifyDataSetChanged(); to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); because it was showing "can't resolve method" error. Problem is after deleting files through filemanager when i open app, it still shows list items in listview which has been deleted but when i click on any item, it opens player activity and couldn't play it then i click back to return to main activity then it refresh sqlite database and listview is now empty.

Comment: I want it to refresh or update sqlite entries when MainActivity starts and show only those items whose files are stored in its folder on sd card.